# "Open In" with dynamically generated file fails in iOS 8

Tags: ios, filesystems, nsdata, uidocumentinteraction

I use this code to save some PDF data to a file, send it to another app using the "Open In" menu, then delete the file when that's done:

```
- (void)openIn:(NSData *)fileData {
    // save the PDF data to a temporary file
    NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.pdf", self.name];
    NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Documents/%@", NSHomeDirectory(), fileName];
    BOOL result = [fileData writeToFile:filePath atomically:TRUE];
    if (result) {
        NSURL *URL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
        UIDocumentInteractionController *controller = [[UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:URL] retain];
        controller.delegate = self;
        [controller presentOpenInMenuFromBarButtonItem:self.openInButton animated:TRUE];
    }
}

- (void)documentInteractionControllerDidDismissOpenInMenu:(UIDocumentInteractionController *)controller {
    // when the document interaction controller finishes, delete the temporary file
    NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.pdf", self.name];
    NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Documents/%@", NSHomeDirectory(), fileName];
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:filePath error:nil];
}
```

This has worked fine until iOS 8. Now, the file is created and I can verify that it contains the correct content, the Open In menu appears, I can select an app, and the delegate method runs and cleans up the file. But instead of iOS switching to the selected app and copying the file into it as it did before, the Open In menu simply closes when I select an app, and the file is not copied.

This works if I give the UIDocumentInteractionController an existing file. It also works if I use the provided fileData but change the destination filename to the filename of an existing file. This suggests a permissions problem -- as if new files are created in iOS 8 with default permissions that UIDocumentInteractionController can't read.

Does anyone know what's happening and how I can work around it?

Comment: Your code for building the path isn't correct. Search for code using `NSDocumentDirectory`.

Comment: You may also want to use the `didEndSendingToApplication` delegate method before deleting the file.

Comment: I don't think the code for building the path is the problem ... I can use the fileExists method on that path after saving the file, and it returns true. And the code works fine if I replace self.name with the name of another file that lives in the Documents directory.

Comment: I did add the didEndSendingToApplication method, and it is not called with these temp files, which isn't surprising since the documentInteractionController isn't actually sending the files. I also added willBeginSendingToApplication and that is called, so it seems that the documentInteractionController tries to send the file but fails.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26564184/uidocumentinteractioncontroller-broken-in-ios-8/26713858#26713858
I also had this exact same problem and avoided it by using didEndSendingToApplication, The files are being sent and didEndSendingToApplication is called for every app except of the mail and sms applications.

Comment: I don't think that's the same problem. didEndSending is only called if the files are successfully sent, and mine are not. My problem only occurs with files that were created by the app in iOS 8. Files that were created before iOS 8 or files that were created in other apps and copied into this app are fine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like the order of operations has changed slightly in iOS 8. DidDismissOpenInMenu used to run after the file was finished sending, but now it runs after the file begins sending. This means my cleanup code was sometimes running before the file was finished sending, leaving no file to send. I figured this out after noticing that smaller files were being sent okay; apparently the processing for smaller files was finishing before my cleanup code got them, but the processing for larger files was not.

To ensure the correct timing, but also clean up files that are created when the user opens the DocumentInteractionController and then dismisses the controller without doing anything, I changed my methods like this:

```
- (void)openIn:(NSData *)fileData {
    // save the PDF data to a temporary file
    NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.pdf", self.name];
    NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Documents/%@", NSHomeDirectory(), fileName];
    BOOL result = [fileData writeToFile:filePath atomically:TRUE];
    if (result) {
        self.sendingFile = FALSE;
        NSURL *URL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
        UIDocumentInteractionController *controller = [[UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:URL] retain];
        controller.delegate = self;
        [controller presentOpenInMenuFromBarButtonItem:self.openInButton animated:TRUE];
    }
}

- (void)documentInteractionController:(UIDocumentInteractionController *)controller willBeginSendingToApplication:(NSString *)application {
    // the user chose to send the file, so we shouldn't clean it up until that's done
    self.sendingFile = TRUE;
}

- (void)documentInteractionControllerDidDismissOpenInMenu:(UIDocumentInteractionController *)controller {
    if (!self.sendingFile) {
        // the user didn't choose to send the file, so we can clean it up now
        [self openInCleanup];
    }
}

- (void)documentInteractionController:(UIDocumentInteractionController *)controller didEndSendingToApplication:(NSString *)application {
    // the user chose to send the file, and the sending is finished, so we can clean it up now
    [self openInCleanup];
    self.sendingFile = FALSE;
}

- (void)openInCleanup {
    // delete the temporary file
    NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.pdf", self.name];
    NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Documents/%@", NSHomeDirectory(), fileName];
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:filePath error:nil];
}
```

**Update for iOS 11**

Before iOS 11, it seems that the operating system kept a copy of the file available until the receiving app was finished reading it, even though my cleanup function ran as soon as the file was sent out from my app. In iOS 11, this changed and the receiving app fails to read the file because my app deletes it before that's done. So now instead of saving the temporary file to Documents and using the `openInCleanup` method to delete it immediately, I'm saving the temporary file to tmp and emptying the tmp folder next time the app launches. This approach should also work with older iOS versions. Just remove `openInCleanup`, change Documents to tmp in the paths, and add this to `applicationDidFinishLaunching`:

```
// clear the tmp directory, which will contain any files saved for Open In
NSString *tmpDirectory = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/tmp", NSHomeDirectory()];
NSArray *tmpFiles = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:tmpDirectory error:NULL];
for (NSString *tmpFile in tmpFiles) {
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", tmpDirectory, tmpFile] error:NULL];
}
```

Comment: After two hours of searching and getting more and more frustrated, I've your post! You've saved my night!!

Answer (score 1):

After reading this post, I already hoped to have found the solution to a similar problem:
For me, as of iOS 8, sharing was only working with Mail.app. It was failing for Dropbox, etc.

Turns out it was something else:
On my interactionController I was setting an annotation like this:

```
interactionController.annotation = @"Some text"
```

For unknown reasons, this prevented Dropbox to open at all. There were no error messages or anything. Removing this line solved the issue.