# UIDocumentInteractionController broken in iOS 8

Tags: ios8, tableview, share, cell

The related code below worked perfect when i was building for iOS 7, but it seems now in iOS 8, it's not working properly.

By properly, I mean in the sense where it's not actually sending the file or whatever to the chosen app.

Example: If I selected Mail, it would open the mail app with the image or zip I chose in the text field. Now it won't send and it takes forever to call/dismiss the UIDocumentInteractionController.

What am I doing wrong?

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];

    NSString *fileName = [directoryContents objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *path;
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    path = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Downloads"];
    path = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];


    documentController = [[UIDocumentInteractionController alloc] init];
    documentController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]];
    [documentController setDelegate:self];
    [documentController presentOptionsMenuFromRect:CGRectZero inView:self.view animated:YES];
    [documentController retain];

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have been playing around with the `UIDocumentInteractionController` and Delegate trying to fix a similar problem, the controller opened-up alright but selecting an application caused it to close without doing anything, my delegate method `documentInteractionControllerDidDismissOpenInMenu` also run alright afterwards.

In the console i got the notification **enabledRemoteNotificationTypes is not supported in iOS 8.0 and later.**

It turns out that this problem will accrue when one of these delegate methods is called :

```
documentInteractionControllerDidDismissOpenInMenu
documentInteractionControllerDidDismissOptionsMenu
```

(and possibly others, i did not check all of them)

I did not find any comment in the **IOS Development Library** or the **UIDocumentInteractionController.h** about these methods not supported for IOS 8.1 but at this point i cant find any other explanation.

## Solution :

i replaced `documentInteractionControllerDidDismissOpenInMenu`
with `didEndSendingToApplication`
and it solved the problem for me.

Comment: When I was coding for iOS 7, I didn't use documentInteractionControllerDidDismissOpenInMenu
documentInteractionControllerDidDismissOptionsMenu, As it stands right now, I'm still not using it.

Comment: Try to remove the delegate completely, Is it sending ?
What other delegate methods you implement ?
Also, what is written in the console output when it fails to send ?

Comment: What's posted in the OP is all that relates to it. As for what outputs when it fails is a whole bunch of 634e653a etc etc for a long time, follow by: <UIPrintInfo: 0x7ff3f4937da0>"
)
viewServiceDidTerminateWithError: Error Domain=_UIViewServiceInterfaceErrorDomain Code=3 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (_UIViewServiceInterfaceErrorDomain error 3.)" UserInfo=0x7ff3f4b5d440 {Message=Service Connection Interrupted}
<MFMailComposeRemoteViewController: 0x7ff3f4b7bd40> timed out waiting for fence barrier from com.apple.MailCompositionService

Comment: Are you running on simulator ?
The simulator 8.1 is crashing for MFMailComposeRemoteViewController
Try running on an actual device

Comment: That's what I gathered from reading up on the subject. However I have no iOS device to test on. Going to try and get a couple people I know.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! This is confirmed to fix my problem.